# How to change custom post type pemalink Hierarcy

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

When we set permalink as `Post name` and go to wordpress any default post Like "Testing 123" single page its link looks like this

```
localhost/foo_articles/testing-123
```

Now i when we change our permalink to `Custom Structure` and set value like `%category%/%postname%`, the link looks like this

```
http://localhost/foo_articles/testing/testing-123/
```

testing is my category slug

**Now the main part of my question is**

I make a plugin where i create a post type `foo_articles` and custom taxonomy `foo_categories`

Its work perfectly. When i click on a category its link looks like this

```
http://localhost/foo_articles/foo_category/junk-food/
```

and when i click on an article for a single page, its link looks like this

```
http://localhost/foo_articles/foo_articles/how-to-reduce-the-intake-of-junk-food-in-children/
```

foo_articles is my post type and its a change able

Now my question is how can i set links that when a user set permalinks `Custom Structure` and set value like `%category%/%postname%` my link also change like above default post single page.

```
http://localhost/foo_articles/article cat slug/how-to-reduce-the-intake-of-junk-food-in-children/
```

Here is custom post type code:

```
add_action('init', 'foo_articles');
function foo_articles() {

    $foo_slug = 'foo_articles';
    $foo_slug = get_option('foo_plugin_slug');

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  =>  __('Foo', 'fff'),
        'singular_name'         =>  __('Foo', 'fff'),
        'all_items'             =>  __('Articles', 'fff'),
        'add_new'               =>  __('New Article', 'fff'),
        'add_new_item'          =>  __('Add New Article', 'fff'),
        'edit_item'             =>  __('Edit Article', 'fff'),
        'new_item'              =>  __('New Article', 'fff'),
        'view_item'             =>  __('View Articles', 'fff'),
        'search_items'          =>  __('Search Articles', 'fff'),
        'not_found'             =>  __('Nothing found', 'fff'),
        'not_found_in_trash'    =>  __('Nothing found in Trash', 'fff'),
        'parent_item_colon'     =>  ''
    );

    $foo_rewrite = array(
        'slug'          =>  FOO_PLUGIN_SLUG, // i define this in plugin index file
        'with_front'    =>  true,
        'pages'         =>  false,
        'feeds'         =>  true,
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                =>  $labels,
        'public'                =>  true,
        'publicly_queryable'    =>  true,
        'show_ui'               =>  true,
        'query_var'             =>  true,
        'menu_icon'             =>  plugin directory.'images/icon-foo.png',
        'capability_type'       =>  'post',
        'hierarchical'          =>  false,
        'menu_position'         =>  3,
        'supports'              =>  array('title','editor','thumbnail','comments','tags'),
        'rewrite'               =>  $foo_rewrite,
        'show_in_menu'          =>  true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     =>  true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     =>  true,
        'can_export'            =>  true,
        'has_archive'           =>  true,
        'exclude_from_search'   =>  true
    );

    register_post_type( 'foo_articles' , $args );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'foo_taxonomies', 0 );

// Article taxonamy
function foo_taxonomies() {
    // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
    $labels = array(
        'name'              =>  __( 'Article Category', 'fff'),
        'singular_name'     =>  __( 'Article Category', 'fff' ),
        'search_items'      =>  __( 'Search Article Category', 'fff' ),
        'all_items'         =>  __( 'All Article Categories', 'fff' ),
        'parent_item'       =>  __( 'Parent Article Category', 'fff' ),
        'parent_item_colon' =>  __( 'Parent Article Category:', 'fff' ),
        'edit_item'         =>  __( 'Edit Article Category', 'fff' ),
        'update_item'       =>  __( 'Update Article Category', 'fff' ),
        'add_new_item'      =>  __( 'Add New Article Category', 'fff' ),
        'new_item_name'     =>  __( 'New Article Category Name', 'fff' ),
    'menu_name'         =>  __( 'Categories', 'fff' )
    );  

    register_taxonomy( 'foo_categories', array( 'foo_articles' ), array(
        'hierarchical'      =>  true,
        "labels"            =>  $labels,
        "singular_label"    =>  __( 'Foo Category', 'foo'),
        'show_ui'           =>  true,
        'query_var'         =>  true,
        'rewrite'           =>  array( 'slug' => 'foo_category', 'with_front' => true )
    ));
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

**Note:** i change my post type slug by plugin settings and its `option_name` is `foo_plugin_slug` (its a client idea)

So please tell me how can i do this. Is there any hook or filter or htaccess code

Comment: Doesn't this belong over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ?  Some mighty talented folks are monitoring that site.

Comment: post single page = `http://localhost/foo_articles/foo_articles/how-to-reduce-the-intake-of-junk-food-in-children/`  is that right?   `foo_articles` x 2?   [quote] Now my question is how can i set links that when a user set permalinks Custom Structure and set value like %category%/%postname% my link also change like above default post single page.[/quote]

Comment: `$foo_slug = 'foo_articles';
    $foo_slug = get_option('foo_plugin_slug');`  Its not clear on what's intended here.

Comment: $foo_slug = get_option('foo_plugin_slug'); is a post type slug, that a user can change

Comment: I don't think you are there yet.  check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option  You might also look at the options table in your mySQL database via phpmyadmin...

Comment: i check every thing .... its work perfectly ... now only i want to change slug permalink

Comment: when you `<?php echo get_option( 'foo_plugin_slug' ); ?>`  what do you see?  `false` or something from here."http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference"    I would have thought you would be using  `add_option()` or `update_option()` ?

Comment: o brother why you confuse at get option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73058/discussion-between-zipzit-and-deemi).

Comment: Do you want that if your visitor open `http://localhost/foo_articles/article cat slug/how-to-reduce-the-intake-of-junk-food-in-children/` He will see the single article `how-to-reduce-the-intake-of-junk-food-in-children` heaving post type `foo_articles` and `category article` cat slug ???

Comment: yes bro ... when user go to single page the link shoud be above

Comment: can you tell me value of FOO_PLUGIN_SLUG??

Comment: its dynamical value in plugin settings an input filed name plugin slug .. a user put any value in this field and i get a value and store in a constant

Comment: Instead of using and `option_name` [allow users to create categories][1]. 


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14060/allow-contributors-to-add-categories-but-not-delete

Answer (score 1):

You can use WP Walker concept. Please check this

[WP Walker](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker)

Eg:

Use **ACF plugin** to get custom field.

**List pages code :-**

```
       $args = array(
          'child_of'     => $post->ID,
          'date_format'  => get_option('date_format'),
          'post_type'    => 'page',
          'title_li'     => __(''),
          'walker'       => new my_page_walker 
        ); 

        wp_list_pages( $args );
```

Extend Walker_page in function.php

**In function.php**

```
class my_page_walker extends Walker_Page {
    public function start_el( &$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_page = 0 ) {
        if ( $depth ) {
            $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
        } else {
            $indent = '';
        }

        $css_class = array( 'page_item', 'page-item-' . $page->ID );

        if ( isset( $args['pages_with_children'][ $page->ID ] ) ) {
            $css_class[] = 'page_item_has_children';
        }

        if ( ! empty( $current_page ) ) {
            $_current_page = get_post( $current_page );
            if ( $_current_page && in_array( $page->ID, $_current_page->ancestors ) ) {
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_ancestor';
            }
            if ( $page->ID == $current_page ) {
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_item';
            } elseif ( $_current_page && $page->ID == $_current_page->post_parent ) {
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
            }
        } elseif ( $page->ID == get_option('page_for_posts') ) {
            $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
        }
        $css_classes = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'page_css_class', $css_class, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page ) );

        if ( '' === $page->post_title ) {
            $page->post_title = sprintf( __( '#%d (no title)' ), $page->ID );
        }

        $args['link_before'] = empty( $args['link_before'] ) ? '' : $args['link_before'];
        $args['link_after'] = empty( $args['link_after'] ) ? '' : $args['link_after'];

        $page_permalink   = get_permalink( $page->ID );

        $user_defined_link =  get_field('my-custom-field',$page->ID)['url'];
        if (!is_null($user_defined_link)) {
            $page_permalink = $user_defined_link; 
        }

        $output .= $indent . sprintf(
            '<li class="%s"><a href="%s">%s%s%s</a>',
            $css_classes,
            $page_permalink,
            $args['link_before'],
            apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ),
            $args['link_after']
        );

        if ( ! empty( $args['show_date'] ) ) {
            if ( 'modified' == $args['show_date'] ) {
                $time = $page->post_modified;
            } else {
                $time = $page->post_date;
            }

            $date_format = empty( $args['date_format'] ) ? '' : $args['date_format'];
            $output .= " " . mysql2date( $date_format, $time );
        }
    }

}
```

The final link will be the value from the custom field.